# Can we have any command to check namenode metadata

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

Iam new to Hadoop, and have one question like, can we have any command to check namenode metadata in tabular format.

Like if i want to check in which exact particular format does namenode saves data in FsImage.

Please help me if there is some particular command which i have missed in my investigation.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop [offline image viewer](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsImageViewer.html) will do it.

Syntax :
 **hdfs oiv -i path/to/fsimage/file -o destination/file**

by using this, we can convert namenode logs into **text** and **xml** files.